# CTEs count and sum

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum

I am trying to get the sum of the count I did on "cll.Claim_number" column.The below CTE is part of 3 othe CTEs and the CTEs run perfectly but now I want to only bring in the "sum" of "COUNTOFSERVICES" from the count I did on cll.Claim_number. I want the output field to have only the sum with the rest of the fields I call out that's it not the count. Below is what I have but it gives both the count and sum in the output when I only want the sum . Thanks

```
Select 
cll.company_desc as state,
cll.line_of_business_desc as Lineofbus,
cll.product_desc as Product,
cll.paymentdate as YearMonth,
cll.typeofservice,
prt.prov_type_short_desc as ProviderSpecialty,
cll.whole_claim_status_desc as Outcome,
count(cll.Claim_number) as "COUNTOFSERVICES",
sum(cll.Claim_number) as total
from claims cll

left join dw.DIM_PROVIDER_TYPE prt -- bringing in provider spec from claim
on cll.prov_type_dim_id = prt.prov_type_dim_id

Where cll.uniquerow = '1'--dedupping


Group By 
cll.company_desc,
Cll.line_of_business_desc,
cll.product_desc,
cll.paymentdate,
--cll.memb_dim_id,
cll.typeofservice,
prt.prov_type_short_desc,
cll.whole_claim_status_desc,
cll.Claim_number
```

Comment: Remove Claim_number from GROUP BY.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to post my code it got extacly what I was looking for . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jarlh

I removed the cll.claimnumber from Group and did the below and I got exactly what I was looking for . I also removed the sum since the count did exactly what I wanted after removing the claimnumber from GROUP.

```
Providers as (

Select 
cll.company_desc as state,
cll.line_of_business_desc as Lineofbus,
cll.product_desc as Product,
cll.paymentdate as YearMonth,
cll.typeofservice,
prt.prov_type_short_desc as ProviderSpecialty,
cll.whole_claim_status_desc as Outcome,
count(cll.Claim_number) as "COUNTOFSERVICES"
--sum(cll.Claim_number) as total --removed
from claims cll

left join dw.DIM_PROVIDER_TYPE prt -- bringing in provider spec from claim
on cll.prov_type_dim_id = prt.prov_type_dim_id

Where cll.uniquerow = '1'--dedupping


Group By 
cll.company_desc,
Cll.line_of_business_desc,
cll.product_desc,
cll.paymentdate,
--cll.memb_dim_id,
cll.typeofservice,
prt.prov_type_short_desc,
cll.whole_claim_status_desc



)  select * from providers
```